# Motion Layout freeze during play animation

Tags: android, xml, android-animation, android-motionlayout

I have made a simple animation to show when an activity starts.
this is my animation:

[image]

The problem is on emulator sometimes animation plays correctly but sometimes freeze and I have to reopen the app. and on my phone it always freeze.

What I have done is I have made 2 separate layout one for "start" and the other for "end" scene
and in start layout I increased left margin of my moving views. following code belong to my moving image.

one of moving views in start XML file:

```
.
.
 <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
        android:id="@+id/metal_iv"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_marginStart="400dp"

        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/backgroundMarginRegisterActivity"
        android:background="@drawable/background_gray"
        android:elevation="-1dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/OnlyOneCorner"/>
.
.
```

in XML end layout I have reduced left margin:

```
android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
```

and this is my scene.xml file:

```
<MotionScene 
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@layout/activity_end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@layout/activity_start"
        motion:autoTransition="animateToEnd"
        motion:duration="1000">
    </Transition>
</MotionScene>
```

I don`t know that is related or not, but the start and end scene does not show in design view window.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem . actually at this time the latest version of constraint dependency is beta8. But downgrading to this version solved my problem:

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta3'
```